# Convert a bitmap to a fixed size

Tags: android, image, bitmap

For example, I have a 10mb image; which I want to convert to 300kb. I have been through many examples
used

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

(here changing 100 to a lesser value will decrease the size but how would it result in a size close to 300-350kb)

and

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
```

where I provided

`options.inSampleSize = 5 /*sample*/;`

But somehow I am missing something.

**UPDATE**
Settled with conversion 11mb to 2mb. Will update if I find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I think because PNG is lossless, the quality parameter has no effect. It's not going to "crunch" your PNGs. However this approach would work for jpg:

Trial and error, with a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) will get you close very quickly, 3-4 attempts probably depending on the size of the acceptable range.

```
int minQuality = 10;
int maxQuality = 100;
long size = 0;
while(true) {
  int mid = (maxQuality + minQuality)/2;        
  long size = compress(mid);

  if (size > minSize) { //too large
     if (maxQuality == minQuality){
       throw new RuntimeException("Cannot compress this image down in to this size range.");
     }
     maxQuality = mid - 1;
     continue;
  }

  if (size < maxSize) { //too small
     if(maxQuality == 100){
       break; //this means the image is smaller than the acceptable range even at 100
     }
     minQuality = mid + 1;
     continue;
  }

  break;//done, falls in range 
}
```

Comment: where am I supposed to use this quality? in bitmap.compress? if yes, then I even used quality upto 1% it returned image worth 2mb

Comment: Yes not every image can compress to a size you desire. Especially PNG. That's when the exception would throw.

Comment: I actually think the quality parameter has no effect on PNG, but the above would work on JPG.

Comment: yes, you are right.. I just recalled. PNG is loseless. That code was just an example. Let me edit it in question.

Answer (score 0):

Two options available

1. Decrease the contrast of the image using image processing or some image processing api for android or do sampling using image processing api
2. Repeat the bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); for several times by storing the image outside and again reading in each time